# Is there any free library that would allow me to use convolution filters on bitmaps?

Tags: c#, windows, image, forms, bitmap

I'm looking for a free library that would allow me to use convolution filters on bitmaps in c#. 
I've found one that works but unfortunately, I can use 3x3 filter there only. I'm looking for something that would allow me to use matrixes of size 3x3,5x5,7x7...

Comment: Library or software recommendations are discouraged here and this question is likely to be closed as not constructive. See also [Why are “shopping list” questions bad?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/158810/169187) and [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)